# What is the best practice for having private member variables with Constructor functions in ES5

Tags: javascript, jquery, ecmascript-6, ecmascript-5

I read a few articles and questions heres but I still don't understand how to achieve this. The following snippet will help me to explain what I am trying to do:

```
function Employee(id, name, email){
    var _id = id;
    var _name = name;
    this._email = email;
}

Employee.prototype.getId = function(){
    return _id;
}

Employee.prototype.getName = function(){
    return this._name;
}

Employee.prototype.getEmail = function(){
    return this._email;
}
```

I went on to create a couple of instances:

```
var emp1 = new Employee(1,'Brendan Eich','brendaneich@gmail.com');
```

When I am using `var` for variables like `id` & `name` they behave like private members but I cannot access them from methods like `getId()` and `getName()` which are defined on `Employee.prototype`.

On the other hand declaring `email` with `this._email = email` works all fine but this doesn't preserve privacy as i can access it asan  object property directly without the need of an access method.

What i want to know:

1. What is the best way to declare a private variable when using constructor functions?
2. If i use `var` to declare variables then where will it reside in the object?

Comment: The best practice is to set them on `this` with an underscore prefix, like you’re doing with `this._email`. Anything you declare with `var` in the constructor will be inaccessible from outside its scope; those variables do not reside “in” the object at all.

Comment: If you want to enforce privacy you can define the getter methods (and setter methods, if required) within the constructor where they have access to the local variables. `this.getId = function() { return _id }`

Comment: javascript has many features "native" to the language but unfortunately privacy isn't one of those. The overall consensus for developers is to simply prefix any private identifier with an underscore. This tells other develops that they shouldn't touch the identifer but it doesn't prevent them from do that either. [This article by philipwalton explains a way of getting real privacy working in javascript (where external devs can't touch private members)](https://philipwalton.com/articles/implementing-private-and-protected-members-in-javascript/).

Comment: [and this article from douglas crockford explains more native privacy techniques in ES5 terms](http://javascript.crockford.com/private.html)

Comment: @Ryan adding to the curiosity, where do variables declared with `var` reside ?

Comment: @BeingSuman [read crockford's article I referred to](http://javascript.crockford.com/private.html). It's old (from 2001) but it explains how variables declared in the constructor behave in ES3-ES5 terms.

Comment: @BeingSuman: Variables can’t really be said to reside anywhere. They contain values; if those values are accessible at some point in the program, they have to be “in memory”. The important thing is that they’re accessible from within their scope and inaccessible from outside.

Comment: There’s also no point in having “real” privacy (you can get it with `WeakMap`s, but why bother?); don’t use hacks like assigning functions in the constructor to try to get it.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
function Employee(id, name, email){
var _id = id; //private 
var _name = name; //private
this._email = email; //public


  var fooPrivate = function(){
      return ;
  }

  this.getId = function(){ //Public function
    fooPrivate(); //I can only be called inside other member functions
    return _id;
  }


  this.getName = function(){ //Public function
    //Note that you don't use this._name for private variables
    return _name;
  }


  this.getEmail = function(){ //Public function
   return this._email;
  }

}
```

What is the best way to declare a private variable when using constructor functions?

If i use var to declare variables then where will it reside in the object?

```
  function Employee{ //private only accessible here... }
```

Comment: `getName()` would need to `return _name`.

Comment: Your post accomplishes the goal of privacy but I wouldn't recommend using this pattern because you're creating new instances of the methods with each constructor call. If you define the functions on the prototype, then they aren't reused

Comment: I did not know that. Definitely something to keep in mind.

Comment: Opps BIG typo: I meant if you *don't* define the functions on the prototype then, they aren't re-used.

Answer (score 2):

Variables declared with `var` only reside in the scope of the function.

To get private properties, the best you can do is to name them so they are obviously private and hope that people don't come along and mutate them. Underscores are a decent way to do that.

You can also pull fancy tricks with functions and closures, but at the end of the day, they won't be properties.